# Getting data from Word doc form controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-word

I'm building a form in a Word .docm (macro enabled Word 2013 doc) with the aim of programming an Access database to import data from completed forms. I've placed textBox and comboBox controls to receive user input, but I can't get the data back out.

The examples I've seen use the `Document.FormFields` collection like so (in Word):

```
Dim fld as FormField
for each fld in ActiveDocument.FormFields
    Debug.Print fld.Name & " - " & fld.Result.Text
next
```

However in my doc `Document.FormFields` is empty, but `Document.Fields` has 19 elements, which happens to be the number of controls in my form. That's great, except that I can't seem to get the name or value of any of the controls using a `Field` object. `Field.Result.Text` is always blank, and there is no `Field.Name` attribute.

So what's the difference between `Field` objects and `FormField` objects, and why are my controls showing up in `Fields` when all the examples I've seen use `FormFields`?

Am I using the wrong form controls? There are three types (I hope I'm not the only one who thinks this is ridiculous) legacy controls, ActiveX controls, and content controls. I'm using the ActiveX type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things...

1. In MS Word terms, a 'field' doesn't have to be a form field. E.g., an auto-updated date, linked graphic, page number, etc., are all types of 'field' (or at least, were until the most recent versions of Word).
2. For compatibility reasons, it can be better to avoid the ActiveX controls. E.g., the Mac version of Word doesn't support them.
3. For best compatibility I would personally stick to the traditional form controls. Instances are named according to their bookmark name, which is settable by right clicking the control and selecting Properties. In VBA, their data is then got via the FormFields collection; if you want the value for a specific field, use

   `Value = ActiveDocument.FormFields("MyFieldName").Result`

Comment: Thank you! I'm assuming that by `Range` you mean `Result`, which returns a `Range` object.

Comment: @jasongetsdown - `Result` returns a `String`, `Range` a `Range` object. As the former is a bit simpler, I've updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to use the current fields you have, you can get the value or name from the OLEFormat.Object:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(1).OLEFormat.Object.Value
```

Or

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(1).OLEFormat.Object.Name
```

However, I would agree with Chris in recommending that you avoid the ActiveX controls.  As [Microsoft says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140269%28v=office.10%29.aspx), there are a lot of reasons that they aren't the best choice for Word forms, except in very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "legacy" formfields and

```
//key
Application.ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).Range.Fields(1).Code
//value
Application.ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).Result
```

Is the solution I came up with.

I've seen companies use the bookmarks, default values, status / help texts for different purposes as well. Not that I would recommend it, but maybe they are working around an issue I'm not aware of.

I feel like .range is a bit of a hack, but considering it's the range of only the form field, unless form fields or fields can have nested fields, it should be ok.